# How do I check if a value is in a list and then have a variable storing the score increase by 10 each time

Tags: python, list

I have created the following code, but would like the score to increase each time that I is in Y, and then display the increased score, allowing the user to enter their guess 8 times.

```
Y = ["Treasure", "Hi", "Hey", "whoops", "OK", "Hello"]

count=0

while count<9:

    I = str(input("Enter your guess"))
    if I in Y:
        score=+10
        print('Your score is:',score)
    else:
        print("I don't understand")
```

Comment: I don't get what is the problem

Comment: You just need to initialise the score outside of the loop, put `score = 0` above the `while`. Also change to `+=` not `=+`

Comment: Notice whether the input is with capital and lower case as this is important for the in match

Comment: @roganjosh `=+10` funny! and it's accepted because of unary plus operator!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre nicely dodged the `NameError` :). Sadly someone else didn't agree with the observation it seems.

Comment: @roganjosh and the downvote has some opposite effect if the answer is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Two main issues with your current code:

1. You don't set an initial value for `score` prior to entering the loop.
2. You use `=+` instead of `+=` to try and increment the score.

This makes an unfortunate combination of mistakes, because `score = +10` does not throw an error while `score += 10` (the correct way) would have given `NameError`. See the changes below. Beyond that, you then get an infinite loop by not incrementing the `count` on each loop.

```
Y = ["Treasure", "Hi", "Hey", "whoops", "OK", "Hello"]

count=0
score = 0 # Set an initial score of 0, before the loop

while count<9:

    I = str(input("Enter your guess"))
    if I in Y:
        score =+ 10 # Change to += to increment the score, otherwise it's always 10
        print('Your score is:',score)
    else:
        print("I don't understand")
    count += 1
```

Comment: I would appreciate if the downvoter could explain the issue with this answer so that I can address it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is needed to complete the logic is to increment the count by 1 at the end. The incremental operator is `+=` and not `=+`. Another thing is the variable score will need to be initialized at the start. So the final code with comments about the missing parts is shown below.

```
Y = ["Treasure", "Hi", "Hey", "whoops", "OK", "Hello"]

count = 0
score = 0 # initialize the score

while count<9:

    I = str(input("Enter your guess: "))
    if I in Y:
        score+=10 # increment the score
        print('Your score is: %s' % score)
    else:
        print("I don't understand")
    count += 1 # increment the count
```

Comment: Is there any way I can now check an index point in the list, so I enter the index point, say 1, and then if it contains say Treasure the score incremments by 10.

Comment: You should probably use the for loop then along with the enumerate function. check them out

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is an infinite loop. Incrementing count by 1 will make it a definite loop. Also, initialize the score variable to zero. That should work things out.

Comment: Good answer, but if you could show what you mean in code as well that would be preferable